# Sticky footer in react native like flipkart

Tags: react-native, user-interface, sticky-footer

I want to develop a sticky footer that can be scrolled up. Once some part of UI is scrolled then the footer can also be moved up and the rest of the UI is visible. just like the Flipkart product detail page appears.

Comment: Not clear what do you want to achieve. A diagram or sample code which you have tried will be helpful

Comment: if you notice on Flipkart or on big basket app in the product detail page, they have add to cart and buy now button. Those buttons are fixed for product detail. once it starts showing similar products it those two buttons are also moving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a sticky button at bottom
2. Get you element scroll position in srollview
3. Get screen height
4. Calculate approx height from where your element is visible in scrollview
5. Hide the sticky button when your element is visible

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/playful-bagel (view in iphone or android mode)

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  Flatlist,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

var height = Dimensions.get('window').height

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('height::'+height)
  }





  render() {
      return (

         <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}} 
            ref={(s) => this.scrollview = s}
            onScroll= {(event) => {
              // console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)

                  if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >=173) {
                  this.setState({
                    visible:false
                  })
                  }else{
                     this.setState({
                        visible:true
                    })
                  }
              }}

              onScrollEndDrag={(event) => {
                if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >=173) {
                  this.setState({
                    visible:false
                  })
                  }else{
                     this.setState({
                        visible:true
                    })
                  }
              }}
            >
           <View>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>1</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>2</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>3</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>4</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>5</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>6</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>7</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>8</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>9</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>10</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>11</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>12</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>13</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>14</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>15</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>16</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>17</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>18</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>19</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>20</Text>


              <View style={{height:50, width:'100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                <Text>Button</Text>
              </View>

            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>1</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>2</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>3</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>4</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>5</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>6</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>7</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>8</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>9</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>10</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>11</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>12</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>13</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>14</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>15</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>16</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>17</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>18</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>19</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>20</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>1</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>2</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>3</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>4</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>5</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>6</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>7</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>8</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>9</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>10</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>11</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>12</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>13</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>14</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>15</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>16</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>17</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>18</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>19</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>20</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>1</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>2</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>3</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>4</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>5</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>6</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>7</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>8</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>9</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>10</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>11</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>12</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>13</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>14</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>15</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>16</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>17</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>18</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>19</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30, height:50 }}>20</Text>

          </View>


           </ScrollView>

            {this.state.visible==true?
              <View style={{height:50, width:'100%', backgroundColor: 'red', position:'absolute', bottom:0}}>
                <Text>Button</Text>
            </View>:null}



        </View>


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, i got the logic behind it. But since the length of data is unpredictable I don't want to achieve it on calculating height. is it possible to check whether that button in view has been scrolled up or visible?

Comment: You can take help of this library >>>>>>>>>>
https://github.com/yamill/react-native-inviewport

Comment: thank you for your reply. ill give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I tried with inviewport but I am getting an error on it, so I tried alternatives too but nothing worked for me yet. can you please show me It on your snack

Comment: You have to calculate the height as per your content inside scrollview...you have to write your own logic to determine it

Comment: No, as I said height is unpredictable in the scenario, and I tried inviewport and alternatives but libraries either show me some error or warnings.